# Why doesn't TYPO3 have a Page Model in Core?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

When I use the core **PageRepository** (TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageRepository), function **getPage**(), I get an **array** returned and not an **object**, as in many other core repositories.
Then I have to build some "magic" for myself in order to **inject** the ***Categories*** or the **Page Author** as **Objects** to be used in the **Fluid Templates**.
Question is if it is a kind of "design decision" not to provide a Page Model at all?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't make much sense to ship a Extbase `Page` domain model for various reasons:

1. TYPO3 itself wouldn't need it.
2. The model would need to be extremely generic since it cannot know anything about your domain requirements.
3. Due to this the model would be *too generic* for basically any domain requirement which in turn would require you to add your own `Page` domain model anyways.

And yes, the same applies to the shipped `FrontendUser` and related classes and these have been [deprecated with TYPO3v11](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/11.4/Deprecation-94654-GenericExtbaseDomainClasses.html) and will be dropped with TYPO3v12.

Comment: 1. I am not so deep in core and take your word in it, would be nice some explanation anyway.

Comment: 2. I dont think it is a problem to ship a "generic" model that allows to $page->getCategories() or $page->getAuthor->getName()

Comment: I disagree partly. If TYPO3 would drop everything the core wouldn't need, TYPO3 would be nearly useless. I see no reason why one should be able to read the headline of a tt_content object but not be able to read the title of a page object out of the box. But yes, a generic class that just provides all generically available page fields is all we need. So basically just the field getter/setter stuff. Core provides/introduces the 'object' so core should ship an actual class object that everyone extending a page object (e.g. the blog extension) should rely on and extend in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You would not have to build an object out of the array for usage in Fluid.

You can also just pass the array to the view. You would use the `.`-notation just like with an object.

E.g. in the controller:

```
$this->view->assign('page', $page);
```

Fluid:

```
{page.title}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for page.categories[0].pid or page.author.name

Comment: you can fetch these values in the controller and assign just those that you need to the view.

Comment: @JonasEberle yes, but first you need to find those categories via a repository instead of just fetching them like `$page->categories` in controller or `{page.categories}` in fluid. And then again `page` is something that one should have available as an object. One reason of splitting representation (fluid) and programming (extbase) is that its possible two persons each do one of these parts. If thats the case the one doing the fluid stuff should be allowed to expect to be able to access the page object.

Comment: Could/should maybe, it depends on your environment. Many opinionated assumptions.No need to bash on it.

Answer (score 0):

The PageRepository is not used in Extbase context, so there is no Domain modelling here, because it also is used a lot in backend context and on very low level core execution, where Extbase is not available or it would be to much overhead to boot up Extbase.
You can simply map the pages table on to a model of yourself and use proper Domain modelling this way, when using Extbase in your extension. The core does not provide an Extbase Domain model for pages, afaik.

Comment: You can simply map the pages table on to a model of yourself..... How many fields do I need in TYPO3 9-10? I guess it is only to "create" the domain model anyway, and map the MM-Relations .... somehow?

Comment: You can simply use TypoScript to map the pages table. Which fields you need is for you to decide. Relations will be mapped correctly, because there already is a TCA configuration for the pages -> category relation.

Comment: Just because we don't need the objects in Core doesn't mean we don't need them anywhere else. I am not saying we should use an extbase object for all the lowlevel page stuff! But, I mean `page` beside `tt_content` is one of the main `things` that define how a TYPO3 website behaves/looks/feels and we cant access it neither in extbase nor in fluid. Tell me I am not the only one who finds this strange.