# TYPO3 ObjectStorage Domain Model for "Pages"

Tags: model, typo3, extbase

I have custom extension where I want to select pages. I have working TCA and can select pages in backend with render type selectMultipleSideBySide.

But I need ObjectStorage in Domain Model to get datas in controller and view.

```
/**
 * menu
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Page>
 */
protected $menu = null;
```

This code is not working, because this model does not exist. Anyone an idea what to set to get it work?
Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add your own `Page` domain model for the very reason that this is your domain and TYPO3 cannot cover it with a generic `Page` domain model.

Also see [Why doesn't TYPO3 have a Page Model in Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769932/why-doesnt-typo3-have-a-page-model-in-core)